# assign query values to array and output

Tags: php, pdo

```
$batchImage = array();
    $i = 0;
    $sliderImages = $dbh->prepare("select image1, image2, image3, image4 from centres where centre_id = 1 ");
    $sliderImages -> execute();
    $images = $sliderImages -> fetch();
    /*$img_1= $images['image1'];
    $img_2 $images['image2'];
    $img_3 $images['image3'];
    $img_4 $images['image4'];*/
     foreach($images as $image)
     {
         $batchImage[$i] = $image;
         $i++;
     }
     foreach($batchImage as $im)
     {
         echo $im;
     }
```

Comment: remove $i and $i++ and just write `$batchImage[] = $image;`

Comment: Yes thats working but print per result twice. All the values are double at output :   chd1.jpg
chd2.jpg
chd2.jpg
chd3.jpg
chd3.jpg
chd4.jpg
chd4.jpg

Comment: why you are taking 2 foreach for echo image values. just write in foreach `foreach($images as $image)
     {
         echo $image;
     }`

Comment: I have to use the images to run in slider. So i need them in array so I can use it in slider code.

Comment: ok, show us your array output and paste in question. print_r($batchImage);

Comment: output:      Array
(
    [0] => chd1.jpg
    [1] => chd1.jpg
    [2] => chd2.jpg
    [3] => chd2.jpg
    [4] => chd3.jpg
    [5] => chd3.jpg
    [6] => chd4.jpg
    [7] => chd4.jpg
)

Comment: please check db value it seems like in your table center id 1 will exist 2 times because nothing other reason to come it 2 times.

Comment: resulting row is 1. center_id is primary key

Comment: WHAT IS THE BEST WAY TO SET THESE VALUE TO AN ARRAY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default type of array returned by `$sliderImages->fetch()` is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`. Every column is returned with both a named and numeric index. That's why you're seeing each image twice. To get just numeric indexes, use `PDO::FETCH_NUM`.

```
$sliderImages = $dbh->prepare("select image1, image2, image3, image4 from centres where centre_id = 1 ");
$sliderImages->execute();
$batchImage = $sliderImages->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
foreach($batchImage as $im)
{
     echo $im;
}
```

You could also use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` to just get the named indexes.

Comment: The code is working but it print values twice. the output is duplicate. Output is : chd1.jpg chd1.jpg chd2.jpg chd2.jpg chd3.jpg chd3. jpgchd4. jpgchd4.jpg    AND  I want result :  chd1..jpg  chd2.jpg  chd3.jpg  chd4. jpg

Comment: If you changed to `PDO::FETCH_NUM` that shouldn't happen.

Comment: Thanks its working. Yes I placed PDO::FETCH_NUM. Now its work same as I want. Thanks

Comment: PDO::FETCH_NUM to remove duplicacy. And array creation to assign values per variable.

Comment: That's what I said in my answer, isn't that what you did when you said it wasn't working?

Comment: WILL YOU PLEASE SUGGEST ME THE BEST WAY TO ASSIGN COLUMNS DATA TO AN ARRAY WITH DIFFERENT KEY THAT I CAN USE ANYWHERE ELSE WHEREVER I NEED.

Comment: use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. Then it will have keys like `image1`, `image2`.

Comment: yes It is. Thanks due to less reputation I can't vote you. But I appreciate your help. Thanks